# How to ensure that two or more simultaneous requests to a MySQL table don't interfere

Tags: php, mysql, data-integrity

Suppose I have about a 1000 simultaneous requests to a table in my DB which consists of these statements (in order):

```
SELECT
INSERT or UPDATE (could be multiple)
DELETE
```

and I want to make sure that none of the requests interfere with one another and the table is in an updated state for the next incoming request. For example:

```
Request #1 comes in.
Request #2 comes in.
Request #1 starts to get processed.
Request #2 should start only when Request #1 is processed so that the data view is consistent and updated for the next request.
```

I searched for this situation around the web and found out two things that could be of help:

1. Transactions
2. Table Locking

But when I read about Transactions, I found out that while a row is being processed by a transaction, other transactions can still come along and modify that row which defeats my purpose.

Also in case of locking, a column can only be locked in one mode i.e. either in READ or WRITE mode, which again fails to keep the data consistent as while reading a row it may get updated and the data which was just read would become an older version of what the table actually is right now.

Is there a solid way to achieve this which can make sure that no request interferes with another and the table is in an updated state for the next incoming request?

I am using MySQL with PHP if this helps.

Comment: Columns are never locked, only rows. Show some actual tables (`SHOW CREATE TABLE {tablename}`) and the exact SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE statemnts that for a request. If changed the data selected, use [SELECT .. FOR UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html). Handle deadlocks. Table locking is never a solution.

Comment: @danblack Oh yes, rows. And this is a theoretical question I suppose. What it has to do with the exact table structure? I just want to know how to keep a set of few queries isolated from another set at the same time?

Comment: Locking must happen in PHP if you plan to atomize multiple queries and avoid inconsistencies

Comment: @LarsStegelitz How can it be done?

Comment: PHP is the scalable part of infrastructure. Each web request is mean to be able to go through a different PHP thread without shared state. Locking defeats this. Also database writers are really good at writing the mechanisms to avoid all the locking faults, inventing your own is a waste of time and will fail. Understand the aspects of transactions, from `START TRANSACTION`, `SELECT [FOR UPDATE|LOCK IN SHARED MODE]`, isolation levels. Do NOT look at `LOCK TABLES` (to brutal) or `GET_LOCK` (this is inventing your own). Isolation isn't quite a database concept however the ACID aspects can be used

Comment: Ask a more specific question on [DBA exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/). What you did to come up with this assertion 'I found out that while a row is being processed by a transaction, other transactions can still come along and modify that row ' would be a good start because this looks like it needs one of the `SELECT` extensions to achieve this. Locks are placed on table indexes by the server so ensure these match your queries.

Comment: @danblack So, if isolation is not achieved then how database integrity could be maintained? I mean then then the requests would just override each other? Well, thanks for the suggestion. I'll ask this question on DBA.

Comment: my bad, Isolation is the I in ACID. Needed another coffee.